# Send a HashMap using Jersey for REST web service

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I'm using Jersey for a REST webservice.
I want to send a HashMap to the server, but I have a problem. This code works fine if I change parameter of the method to String, but with a HashMap, it doesn't work :

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
    Client client = Client.create(config);

    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8081/serviceProxy_socle-01.00.00-SNAPSHOT/services/tableauDeBord/subventions").build();
    System.out.println(uri.toString());
    WebResource service = client.resource(uri);

    GenericType<TableauDeBordImpl<CoupsDPouceImpl>> informationsDossier = new GenericType<TableauDeBordImpl<CoupsDPouceImpl>>(){};


    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("rne", "0240984P");

    TableauDeBordImpl<CoupsDPouceImpl> content = service
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .entity(params, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).post(informationsDossier);
```

This is the Stacktrace :

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.HashMap, and MIME media type, application/xml, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:642)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:613)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$300(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:503)
    at fr.liberaccess.pool.tester.Tester.testCoupsDpouce(Tester.java:63)
    at fr.liberaccess.pool.tester.Tester.<init>(Tester.java:39)
    at fr.liberaccess.pool.tester.Tester.main(Tester.java:188)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.HashMap, and MIME media type, application/xml, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:299)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:146)
    ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your need to create a [MessageBodyWriter](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) and annotate the class as a Provider.

You also need to tell Jersey about the new provider.

From the user guide.

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(PlanetJAXBContextProvider.class);
Client c = Client.create(cc);
```

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I have a class annotated as Provider for another return type. Can I have many classes annotated as Provider ??

Comment: @taichimaro I believe you can have as many Providers as you want.  Jersey will use the first Provider it can find that will accept the given input and media type.